# Action of edittext in android

Tags: android, android-widget

Motivation: I want when i press enter while passing text in edittext then the work of edittext will be stopped and edittext will be invisible . My code is here

```
edt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);
            edt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            edt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) 
                {
                    if(arg2.getAction()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                    {
                        edt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

But it is not working .What is the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getAction() doesn't give you the keycode. You want to use getKeyCode() instead.

change

```
if(arg2.getAction()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
```

to

```
if(arg2.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
```

also if I understood you correctly, you want the EditText to completely disappear. If you're using a linearlayout or something similar, the EditText will be invisible, but it will still be there, taking up space. If you want the edittext to completely go away, you should use `edt.setVisibilty(View.GONE)` instead of `edt.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE)`